# Paper suggestion STF tensors (Symmetric Trace Free Tensors)

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I am studying STF tensors on the appendix of [this](http://www2.iap.fr/users/blanchet/images/Structure_gravitational_field_BD_1986.pdf) paper and on [the review](http://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/4878668.pdf) by Thorne: could anyone suggest me a wider, more comprensive paper or book?

These are almost a collection of formulae...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MIT had an open course with some pdf on this. Let me find it... OK got it. It seems similar to your appendix but it is 17 pages to your 4. This is the kind of thing that I remember learning a lot about when I was a physics phd student.

link:

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-07-electromagnetism-ii-fall-2012/lecture-notes/MIT8_07F12_ln9.pdf

As I recall this topic is covered extensively in Jackson ([http://www.amazon.com/Classical-Electrodynamics-Third-Edition-Jackson/dp/047130932X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047130932X)) which you may want to check out from a library.

Hope this helps!